# Is there one-byte type in protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I can't find if there is possible to have char / byte type in proto.

I can see various types here:

- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

but I can't find byte type and even int16 types there.

Comment: The non-fixed integer types use variable length encoding so presumably you'd use `int32` for 16 bit and 8 bit integers and let the variable-length-encoding part take care of not sending the bytes you're not using.

Comment: @muistooshort IMHO your comment should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, there is no fixed 1-byte type. Fixed length has 4 and 8 byte variants only. Most other numeric values are encoded as "varint"s, which is variable length depending on magnitude (and sign, but "zigzag" comes into play there). So you can store bytes with value 0-127 in one byte, and 128-255 in two bytes. 16-bit values will take between 1 and 3 bytes depending on magnitude (and sign /zigzag etc).

For multiples, there is "bytes" for the 8-bit version, and "packed" for the rest; this avoids the cost of a field-header per value.

Comment: zigzag only comes for sint variants. normal int variants like int32 will use 10 bytes for negative values.

Comment: IMHO maybe 128~16384 all takes up 2 bytes, instead of 128~255?

Comment: @ch271828n I was explicitly talking about *bytes* with values 128-255 (i.e. the last half of the 8-bit range), but indeed you can store up to 16383 (not 16384) in 2 bytes of varint - i.e. 14 data bits and 2 packing bits